# Laravel 5.6 Nested Categories

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am using Laravel 5.6. I am stuck with the following. The structure of my category model is below.

```
id  | name              | cat_parent_id | slug
--- | ------------------| ------------- | ------------- 
1   | Parent - 1        | NULL          | parent-1 
2   | Parent - 2        | NULL          | parent-2 
3   | Child-1- P - 1    | 1             | ch-1-p-1 
4   | Child-1- P - 2    | 2             | ch-1-p-2 
5   | sCh-1-Ch-1-P- 2   | 4             | sch-1-ch-1-p-2
```

To obtain children relationship I used the following method on the linkedin\Category model.

```
public function children()
{
  return $this->hasMany('linkedin\Category', 'cat_parent_id', 'id');
}
```

In my controller,

```
public function category(Category $category)
{
    $categories = $category->first()->children;

    return view('product.list', compact('categories'));
}
```

Here is my route

```
Route::get('/{category?}','ProductController@category');
```

I am able to fetch the first children using the following code. It shows the following, when I visit the url, http://trump.localhost/parent-2

Child-1- P - 2

However, it doesn't show anything when I visit http://trump.localhost/parent-2/ch-1-p-2

It should show following, but I don't see it.

sCh-1-Ch-1-P- 2

Comment: is App\Category and kblinked\Category is two different models?

Comment: Please post your route(s).

Comment: @afsalc No, it is just one. I corrected the code.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Added Route

Comment: Can you change the URL to `http://trump.localhost/ch-1-p-2`? Or does it have to be `http://trump.localhost/parent-2/ch-1-p-2`?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir it will helpful in  SEO. it has to be http://trump.localhost/parent-2/ch-1-p-2

Comment: How deep can it go?

Comment: Should be Less than 4 at the most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to adjust your route:

```
Route::get('{category1}/{category2?}/{category3?}/{category4?}',
    'ProductController@category');
```

And your controller:

```
public function category(Category $category1, Category $category2 = null,
        Category $category3 = null, Category $category4 = null) {
    $category = collect(func_get_args())->filter()->last();

    $categories = $category->children;

    return view('product.list', compact('categories'));
}
```

Comment: Worked like charm, but I had to change  $categories = $category->first()->children; to  $categories = $category->children;

Comment: I will make changes in the route, and explode it to make it work with n depth.

Answer (score 0):

in model

```
public function children()
{
  return $this->hasMany('kblinked\Category', 'cat_parent_id');
}
```

in your controller send category id in argument then find that category;

```
public function category($category) // $category is id of category
{
    $category = Category::findOrFail($category);

    return view('product.list', compact('categories'));
}
```

in your view

```
@foreach($category->children as $child)
  {{$child->name}}
@endforeach
```

[for more documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

Comment: my route is this.
   
   Route::get('/{category?}','ProductController@category'); 
   and your suggestion resulted in Type error: Too few arguments to function category($category) , 0 passed and exactly 1 expected

Comment: remove question mark from end. Route::get('/{category}', 'ProductController@category')

Comment: Dear Ozal, In search of answers, I forgot one thing that findOrFail is equivalent to where('slug', $category);  Which I have already implemented. What I need to understand is  why 

    $categories = $category->first()->children; 

    is not working

Comment: Hi @Rakeshkumar, you only send $category in function as a string how it can work it is just string I think.

Comment: Well that is the beauty of Eloquent ... Try the code above Y'll see it works. Let me know if it doesn't .